# Going back to original image from image edges

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, derivative

If we read an image X and apply the simplest edge detector F = [1 0 −1] on it to find Y. Is it possible to go back to retrieve X from Y? Given that Yn = Xn−1−Xn+1, can you express X in terms of Y. Can we design a 3x3 filter G that performs the opposite of F?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `X-1` and `X0` are known (say both 0),

```
X1= Y0 + X-1
X2= Y1 + X0
X3= Y2 + X1 = Y2 + Y0 + X-1
X4= Y3 + X2 = Y3 + Y1 + X0
X5= Y4 + X3 = Y4 + Y2 + Y0 + X-1
X6= Y5 + X4 = Y5 + Y3 + Y1 + X0
    ...
```

This is a recursive filter, which computes the prefix sum of every other pixel.

This will only work if you have the signed values of Y. If only the absolute value is available, you are stuck.

Comment: This is `cumsum` plus some constant `X-1`?

Comment: assuming free boundaries conditions(0 at the boundaries) how am I supposed to form a 3x3  filter with this to perform convolution on 2D vector(Y)

Comment: @CrisLuengo: it is not `cusum`, there is no decision threshold.

Comment: @MuhammadHanifSarwari: your question is expressed in 1D. A 3x3 filter makes no sense.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I cannot use a recursive filter is there any way I can get a 1D filter that can be applied using convolution.

Comment: @MuhammadHanifSarwari: no, this does not reduce to a convolution.